# Make iframe full length of browser window and make it scale down as window gets smaller

Tags: html, css, iframe

Been trying this all day trying to get iframe that's full length of window to scale down as broswer window gets smaller without loosing it's aspect ratio.

Here's what I've tried already.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <iframe src="http://www.mundaychevrolet.com" scrolling="no" style="width:100%; height: 100%; transform-scale" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what kind of property is `transform-scale`

Answer (score 2):

**Make iframe full length of browser window**

http://jsfiddle.net/BfLZf/4/
http://jsfiddle.net/BfLZf/4/show

```
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    overflow: auto;
}
iframe {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**and make it scale down as window gets smaller**

For responsive images (scaling ...) http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201306/how_to_proportionally_scale_images_that_have_dimension_attributes/

http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/web/this-is-responsive/

Comment: Not exactly it. You know how if you look at google search pagae no matter what device it looks the same. Thats pretty much what I'm looking for. Or for a better analogy how you scale images while keeps it ratio. I'm trying to do that. Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: Than you need this solution and you need to implement a responsive lay-out using media queries. http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

Since div #wrapper has no height set, iframe takes its default size. The right css in your case is:

```
<style>
html, body, #wrapper{
    width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;
}
</style>


<iframe src="http://www.mundaychevrolet.com" style="width:100%; height: 100%; transform-scale" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<!-- remove scrolling="no" -->
```

Comment: I've actually added the height to 100 percent nothing changed. Also @ Sigma how would you add media queries to an iframe without changing content position and just focus on size

Comment: I checked on Firefox. You can add an image - how your output looks.

Comment: I looked at your example and a image might work. But want I'm doing if a webpage inside a iframe. I just want the page inside the iframe to scale when I make the browser window smaller.

Comment: Check my answer again.